# django-friendship API

Tags: django, django-models

I Think there's nothing much to explain over here of what I am trying to achieve using Django-Friendship API. but it doesnt work and always shows the Unfollow btn.

```
{% if user.id not in request.user.following %}
<a class='btn btn-success' href="{% url 'addFollowing' user.id %}">Follow @{{user.username}} 
</a>
{% else %}
<a class='btn btn-danger' href="{% url 'removeFollowing' user.id %}">Unfollow</a>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got away with it by checking it in view and then sending that variable into template.
but if there's any other solution, guide me.